# How frequently can I expect to cook "special" meals?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Rupees are kinda hard to come by in this game surprisingly, but apples aren't.  So I've been taking up all my excess apples and cooking them together to sell back (from 3RPA to 10RPA cooked). There was one time while cooking Simmered Fruit (5 apples), the music played back was slightly different and I managed to cook a "special" Simmered Fruit.

It's "special" in that it looks exactly the same as the regular Simmered Fruit dish and has no distinctive look or description (and costs the same) but it heals 8 hearts rather than the usual 5.

[image: the "special" simmered fruit]

How often can I expect this to happen?

Comment: Aww man, I lost the save getting that screenshot when I took out the sd card. I'm gonna keep cooking to see if I can get it again. Edit: got it again after the 7th attempt straight. So at least it doesn't seem to happen at a fixed rate.

Comment: Hmmm, after another pass at cooking more meals, I got it again on the second meal after the previous attempt.  This might be testable. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be pretty random, from what I've been able to find. From [this page](http://orcz.com/Breath_of_the_Wild:_Recipes):

> Recipes may acquire random bonuses, such as being boosted from low to mid or have extra hearts. The jingle heard is altered when the results are randomly improved.

[This site](https://www.vg247.com/2017/03/06/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-best-recipe-elixir-hearts-cold-resistance-defense-speed-stealth/) also says that it is random and that it will apply one of a few different effects to your dish.

> On top of these buffs, when cooking you may also hear a special sound. When this happens you will receive an extra bonus at random. These are:
>
> - Extra yellow heart
> - Three extra hearts
> - Buff increase by a further 5 minutes
> - Buff increased by +1
> - Stamina increases

**However**, this article also says that there *is* a way to guarantee this boost.

> You can actually guarantee these bonuses by using particular items or cooking during a certain time.
>
> Cooking during a Blood Moon, when the moon is red and enemies respawn, will give you a random bonus. As will using a star fragment or dragon body part in your recipe.

Thus, it's not yet known the *exact* chance to have this bonus happen to you, but you're able to force it to happen by cooking under certain conditions or using certain ingredients.

Comment: I can definitely confirm the blood moon part. Otherwise, it's obviously random, I think having the rate handy would be very useful.

Comment: @JeffMercado agreed. However, from all the stuff I've seen, everyone is just chalking this occurrence up to "random chance," and no one has concrete numbers, at least not yet. If I find any more information, I'll update this answer, though!

Comment: I've noticed that the chances of getting special food seems to be increased if you use several similar but different ingredients in one dish. For example, if you can combine the iron mushroom, armoranth, and armored carp with two other ingredients, the chances of getting a special iron dish is increased (not guaranteed though). This is completely anecdotal, though, so it might not actually be true.

Comment: To add some more detail: "during a Blood Moon" starts at 11:30 PM (when the blood moon sound effects and ambient effects start) and ends at 12:00 (when the cut scene triggers). I found that in that time I can cook about 1.5 inventory pages of food (around 30 items).